# How does this code work exactly? Help me how to approah the code?

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 6;
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.Write(i++ + " ");
                if (i <= 10)
                    i += 1;
                else
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Output is :- 6 8 10

I am new to programming language, I wondering how it works?
As I have to write output for i++...

so it works like since its i++, it will print 6 1st?

6+1=i then increment with i++ that gives 8 at 2nd 
 8+1=i then increment with i++ that gives 10 at 3rd?

I don't know I'm very confused, can anyone help me is my approach to the answer right?

Answer (score 3):

Its quite simple:

```
int i = 6;
for (; ; ) //-> This is an infinite loop
    {
        Console.Write(i++ + " ");//-> This prints i then increments so you get 6 first
        if (i <= 10) //->This conditions fails when i = 10 and then else part executes
            i += 1; //->Here i gets incremented again hence you get 6 then 8 then 10
        else
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not good code.
When you use a "for" like that, your loop will run forever and only the "break" command will stop it.

Here is better code that does the same:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 6; i <= 10; i+=2)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Read more about [For loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

Comment: I think the original code was _deliberately_ written in a confusing way to test people's understanding. In other words, it's a test question, not an actual live code, and the asker is asking for help to answer the test question. (That's just how it appears to me, I could be wrong though.)

Comment: @SFLee - Agreed - this does not actually answer what OP was looking for. OP did not ask for Code improvement. OP wanted the working logic behind the current code.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed deliberately written that way, I just wanted to know that if i am approaching the code in right way...

Comment: @al-Acme I think Amiros answer more better, since any one can understand this code even after first teaching class of C# or c programming.

Comment: I did explain whats "tricky" in his code. for(;;) is exactly like while(true) - makes the loop run forever. After you know that, I'm pretty sure you know what the code prints.
Anyway, that's why this is a forum.. If all the answers were the same boring ones then we would learn less.

Comment: why did you delete your answer? this is not a competition and each good answer should stay here for future visitors..

Comment: I think `for (;;)` is not the only tricky part in the code. The other one is the behaviour of `i++`.

Comment: if you dont know what i++ means then you need to start from the basics(before getting into loops - since the basic for loop uses i++ most of the time to go forward).